# C++ lua - effectively retrieve metatable from registry

Tags: c++, lua

Currently, for creating metatable object for lua in C++ im using this code:

```
template <typename T>
static void RegisterObject(lua_State *L, luaL_Reg Functions[], const char *Name)
{
    luaL_newmetatable(L, Name);
    luaL_register(L, NULL, Functions);
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_setfield(L, -1, "__index");
    lua_setglobal(L, Name);
}
```

And for pushing to stack using this:

```
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, /*Object*/);
luaL_getmetatable(L, /*Object Name*/);
lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
return 1;
```

Is there effective way of getting table to push into stack? I don't want to use string to get metatable.

Comment: lightuserdata cannot have a metatable. It's just the pointer value, you need lua_newuserdata to actually have a metatable with one.

Comment: i'm pushing lightuserdata with custom pointer and also pushing metatable with it, when i use metatable function i'm getting that custom pointer and doing some operations with it.

Comment: I have solved by getting field of metatable name by `lua_getfield`, reference it by `lua_ref` and at last get referenced metatable by `lua_rawgeti` (`LUA_REGISTRYINDEX`)

Comment: @BeqaGurgenidze: "*i'm pushing lightuserdata with custom pointer and also pushing metatable with it,*" That's not what your code is saying. `lua_setmetatable` *applies* the table as a metatable to the given object, in this case a light-userdata. That will mean that *all* light-userdata will have that table as their metatable.